# jbpm 5.3 - process instance ID generator

Tags: spring, hibernate, jbpm, business-process-management

I work on a projected based on Spring 3, Hibernate 3.6 and JBPM 5.3. The bpm processes are not persisted up to date, but only from time to time (i.e. once a day).

I create a process session by

```
KnowledgeBuilder kBuilder ...
KnowledgeBase processBase = kBuilder.newKnowledgeBase();
StatefulKnowledgeSession processSession = processBase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
```

and a process instance by

```
ProcessInstance processInstance = processSession.createProcessInstance("sample", null);
```

The problem is when I want to persist the process instance manually

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.saveOrUpdate(processInfo); // processInfo is a instance of ProcessInstanceInfo
```

the ID generated by a database sequence is other than the ID when process started.

My question: is there any way to force

```
processSession.createProcessInstance("sample", null)
```

get a new ID from a custom logic, i.e. from the database sequence?

Thanks!